# How do I fill the Memory Book?

Tags: solatorobo-red-the-hunter

Some guy had me go on a quest to find a Memory Book, which he then gave to me.

He told me that in order to fill it, I had to complete certain actions over and over again to unlock pages that would then "tell me about the world".

What sorts of things to I have to do over and over again in order to fill this book? Does the book do anything useful if I fill it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Que faire?* It unlocks the Library option in the Cabin of the Asmodeus.

It's filled with a lot of lore and backstory (everyday life, differences between the races, currency, history, etc.) about the world (Shepherd) not discussed about or touched upon in game.

All of them have pretty straight forward descriptions, except for Geography (based on playtime, most ppl say ~40 hours should be enough) and Technology (how far you advance in the story/quests). For Races, you can talk to the same person more than once as long as you exit the area and come back (you have to talk to ~25 ppl for it to advance a bit, I think).